# Component not rendering on new page with param

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have two components i'm having this problem with, ChampionLists and SelectedChamp. SelectedChamp is not dependent on the ChampionLists data i'm not passing any data to it Because inside the SelectedChamp i'm fetching new data based on the parameter.

My ChampionLists component is where i render some data using map and each data is wrapped with Link that navigate to champions/select/:param

```
<Link to={`${match.url}/select/${champ.name}`}> Some data infos </Link>
```

Currently inside the ChampionLists i have another Route that match the url and accepts parameter and this renders the SelectedChamp component

```
<Route path={`${match.url}/select/:champName`} exact render={(props) => <SelectedChamp {...props}/>}/>
```

But if i click any data listed it doesn't load to a new page it just renders the SelectedChamp component inside the ChampionLists how would i make it load to a new page?

My index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
<BrowserRouter>    
    <App />
</BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

My app.js

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/" exact render={(props) => <FrontPage toggleGlobalHeader={this.hideGlobalHeader} {...props}/>}/>
  <Route path="/login" render={(props) => <Login user={user} {...props}/>}/>
  <Route path="/champions" render={(props) => <ChampionsList {...props}/>}/>
  <PrivateRoute path="/community" user={user} component={DashBoard}/>
  <Route path="*" render={(props) => <RouteNotFound toggleGlobalHeader={this.hideGlobalHeader} {...props}/>} />
</Switch>
```

i tried adding the  Route inside the app but it didn't load the component.

```
....
<Route path="/champions" render={(props) => <ChampionsList {...props}/>}/>
<Route path="/champions/select/:champName" render={(props) => <SelectedChamp {...props}/>}/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed the "exact" when defining the route for champions. Below code is working for me.

```
<Route exact path="/champions" render={(props) => <ChampionsLists {...props} />} />
<Route path="/champions/select/:champName" render={(props) => <SelectedChamp {...props} />} />
```